# How to combine two different onClick events on the same table in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have the following table structure:

```
<table id='myTable'>
    <tr>
       <th class='sort' field='ticket_id'>Ticket Number</th>
       <th class='sort' field='insert_date'>Insert Date</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class='data_row' ticket_id='123'>
       <td>123</td>
       <td>12-Aug-2014</td>
    </tr>
    ...
    ... so many other rows that are generated by code behind
    ...
</table>
```

and I have the following javascript to handle clicks on `data_row`s

```
$(document).on('click','#myTable tr',function(){
    var ticket_id = $(this).attr('ticket_id');
    get_details_about_ticket(ticket_id);  //this will call a function to display more details
});
```

I also have the following code to handle sorting the table if the user clicks on a certain `<TH>` element

```
$(document).on('click','#myTable.sort',function(){

    var field_id = $(this).attr('field_id');
    sort_table_by_field(field_id);  //this will call a function to re-generate the table 
                                    // with a different ORDER BY 
});
```

The problem is that only one event is triggered. the `<TR class='data_row'>` to be specific. 
I though that this might be caused by me trying to listen to a click on a `<TH>` and on the same time on a `<TR>` which might not be reasonable since a `<TH>` is contained inside a `<tr>` so I decided to do the following to make things unified:

```
$(document).on('click','#myTable td',function(){
    var ticket_id = $(this).parent().attr('ticket_id');
    get_details_about_ticket(ticket_id);  
});

$(document).on('click','#myTable th',function(){
    var field_id = $(this).attr('field_id');
    sort_table_by_field(field_id);
});
```

but still only the `<td>` click event is triggered.

What might be the cause, and how can I trigger both events to do different tasks?

Comment: `'#myTable.sort'` - you need a space between `#myTable` and `.sort`

Comment: Change all `get_details_about_ticket(thicket_id ---> ticket_id)`;

Comment: @ChetanSastry it does not matter if you put space or not between classes. I tried it anyways and it did not work.

Comment: @MartinErnst thanks for notifying me about the typo, but that was not the cause of the problem. This is a simplified prototype of my complex design

Comment: 1. **th** has no attribute `field_id` but `field`.
Change in your <th>-click-func:

    ...$(this).attr('field_id' ---> 'field');

2. I've made a [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/0f5n6wm4/2/) with your code, but included in a `$(document).ready()`. All events work! Maybe you attached the click-handlers to early.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about triggering just one function, on  elements - then in the triggered javascript function, grab the element classes and include logic there to perform one or more functions.

Edit: I worked up the following example:

```
var myHandler = function () {
        if ($(this).is('td')) {
                console.log('found td');
        }
        if ($(this).is('th')) {
                console.log('found th');
        }
}
$(document).on('click', '#myTable td', myHandler);
$(document).on('click', '#myTable th', myHandler);
```

Edited again to make example more similar to your existing code.

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: @Ahmad I added the example. Maybe this will give you some ideas